# How can I retrieve the city a user is in from their current position using expo-location?

Tags: react-native, location, expo

I'd like to get the city from a user's current location when they are on a screen of my app.

I've tried using the `getCurrentPositionAsync` function from expo-location but it's not working.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
     export default class Ranking extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          location: {},
          errorMsg:'',
          },
        };
      }
    
      _getLocationAsync = async () => {
        let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
        if (status !== "granted") {
          this.setState({
            errorMsg: "Permission to access location was denied"
          });
        }
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        this.setState({ location });
        };
    
      UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        this._getLocationAsync();
      }
    
      render() {
        let text = 'Waiting...';
         if (this.state.errorMsg) {
           text = this.state.errorMsg;
         } else if (location) {
           text = JSON.stringify(location);
       }
    
    return (
      <View>
         <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location)` function to get a postal address that has a `city` field corresponding to the location you passed in.

This function takes a location object as a parameter that has a `latitude` and a `longitude` property.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationreversegeocodeasynclocation.

---

From looking at your example you could pass `location.coords` as a parameter to `Location.reverseGeocodeAsync` and retrieve the city name something like this:

```
class Ranking extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      address: null,
      errorMsg: null,
    };
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        errorMsg: 'Permission to access location was denied',
      });
    }
    const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    const address = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords);
    this.setState({ address });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
  }

  render() {
    let text = 'Waiting...';
    if (this.state.errorMsg) {
      text = this.state.errorMsg;
    } else if (this.state.address) {
      text = this.state.address[0].city;
    }
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Also use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`. `componentWillMount` is considered as "legacy".

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#legacy-lifecycle-methods.

Comment: Thank you for answering me and taking the time to explain. 
I used your help to modify my code but I still only get "Waiting..." on my screen (I tried it with my phone, not the emulator)

Comment: You say you've modified your own code based on mine, but have you also tried to render my example as is? Because I've also changed other things like the state and the if-else statement inside render. If either `this.state.errorMsg` or `this.state.address` is not null you won't see "Waiting...". So if you do see it log out `status`, `location` and `address` to see what's happening.